# get specific data values from html in php without using js

Tags: php, html

i'm new to php  and i'm passing an  attribute in html and  i want  to get  the  value  in php in the  next page html code:

```
 <li><a class="md-font gray products-group" data-group="<?php echo $group['group_id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $brand['brand_id']; ?>"><?php echo $group['title']?></a></li>
```

php  code:

```
 elseif ($filter == "group-products"){
          $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
          $products_req=Products::get_products_by_brand_id_lang($id,$page,$size);
      }
```

in this  case  i'm getting brand _id  value  how to get group_id ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: @Swellar no pure php

Comment: I can't seem to see the `href` in your link, how do you go to the next page using `<a>`

Comment: If you need to send data to the server you need to add hidden inputs or add them to the url.

Comment: Is this relevant, `Products::get_products_by_brand_id_lang($id,$page,$size)`? If so, can you show the codes inside the function?

Comment: If you can use `href` in a link, you can use `$_GET` to pass data to another page

Comment: @Swellar i'm using javascript in another  places to go to the  next page

Comment: @jeroen i need  just  to get  data-group value  do you know  any way to do this ?

Comment: Are you posting a form or following a link? Depending on that, see my previous comment.